# Show that $\tanh(x)-\frac{x}{a}$ has at most three real zeros using Rouché's theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, roots

Consider a function
\begin{align}
f(x)=\tanh(x)-ax, \,x\in \mathbb{R},
\end{align}
for some $a\in (0,1)$.  We want to show that this function has at most three real zeros.
Note, this is an easy thing to prove. Observe the following facts; 1) function is odd, 2)function is $f(0)=0$, and 3) $f'(0)>0$, and $f(\infty)=-\infty$.

**Question:** However, I want to show this fact using complex analysis. Specifically, I would like to prove it using [Rouché's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%27s_theorem).

Comment: do you mean three real zeroes, as there are infinitely many complex ones?

Comment: @Conrad Correct. Let me fix it.

Comment: Pardon me for asking, but why would 1, 2 and 3 ensure the function has at most one zero on $]0,\infty[$? If you replace $\mbox{tanh}$ with $\sin$, you have the same properties (and possibly arbitrarily large amount of zeroes as $a\to 0$)

Comment: @charmd while you are of course right that 1,2,3 are not enough, $f'$ is decreasing (from $1-a$ to $-a$) on $[0, \infty)$ which in addition to 1,2,3 is enough since then $f$ has a local maximum at the unique root of $f'=0$ on $(0, \infty)$ and that maximum is positive so on $(0, \infty)$ there is only one zero of $f$ somewhere to the right of that